# Help Class for Trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test

Can someone help me how to write test class for the below trigger.

```
trigger AccountOwnerUpdate on Account (before insert, before update) {
    Set<Id> accIds = new Set<Id>();
    List<Contact> updatedConList = new List<Contact>();
    List<Account> accList = new List<Account>();
    Map<Id, String> newOwnerIds = new Map<Id, String>();    
    
    for(Account acc : trigger.new) {
        system.debug('entered here');
        accIds.add(acc.Id);
        newOwnerIds.put(acc.Id, acc.Coverage_Lead__c);
        
        if(acc.Coverage_Lead__c != NULL) {
            acc.OwnerId = acc.Coverage_Lead__c;
        }
        if(acc.Coverage_Lead__c == NULL){
            acc.OwnerId = acc.LastModifiedById;                
        }
    }
    
    for(Account accs : [SELECT Id, LastModifiedById, (SELECT Id, Owner.Id FROM Contacts)
                        FROM Account WHERE Id IN:accIds]) {
                            String newOwnerId = newOwnerIds.get(accs.Id);
                            //String oldOwnerId = oldOwnerIds.get(acc.Id);    
                            
                            if(newOwnerIds.get(accs.Id) != NULL) {
                                system.debug('Coverage_Lead__c !=');
                                for(Contact con : accs.Contacts) {
                                    con.OwnerId = newOwnerIds.get(accs.Id);
                                    updatedConList.add(con);
                                }
                            }
                            if(newOwnerIds.get(accs.Id) == NULL) {
                                system.debug('Coverage_Lead__c ==');
                                for(Contact con : accs.Contacts) {
                                    con.OwnerId = accs.LastModifiedById;
                                    updatedConList.add(con);
                                }   
                            }
                            
                        }
    update updatedConList;
}
```

I am new to test apex so please help me how to write test class for the above trigger. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I have voted to close this question as I see all your previous 3 questions are about writing test classes. I would suggest to spend some time looking at trailheads and write the test cases. We would be really love to help if you stuck with some specific issue.

Comment: @manjit5190 I've written test class for the above trigger by taking reference. Though I was not able to cover all the functionality in trigger. I was not able to cover for loop in the trigger using test class. Can you help me how to resolve it ..